# Regular Expression to check for words

Tags: regex

Here is my regular expression:

```
@"\<\\{+(TITLE|BODY|DATE|CALENDARID|CALENDARSUBSCRIPTIONGUID|CALENDARURL|TIME|CONTACTS|LOCATION|URLINFO)\\}+\\>"
```

It needs to check for words like {Title}. Have I made it correctly?

Comment: Why don't you test it and find out? This is a perfect place to write some unit tests to make sure it matches some strings that *should* match and doesn't match other strings that *shouldn't* match.

Comment: @Adam Which one is the perfect place for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks ok to me.  You might want to have the -i switch to make your expression case insensitive unless you only want to match "TITLE" and not "title" for example.  Here is a pretty good regex checker:  [RegEx Pal](http://regexpal.com/).  I noticed you didn't flag a language and the previous link was a javascript regex tester.  Here are some more resources [Regex Lib resources page](http://regexlib.com/Resources.aspx)